# HttpWebRequest works. WebClient.UploadFile doesn't

Tags: wcf, file-upload, httpwebrequest, webclient

I thought I figured out a way to simplify my code by **using WebClient.UploadFile instead of HttpWebRequest**, but I end up getting a file on the server end that is a few dozen bytes too short and corrupted. Any idea where the bug lies?

Thanks

**Using HttpWebRequest (works fine):**

```
       HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest
                                 .Create("http://" +
                                  ConnectionManager.FileServerAddress + ":" +
                                  ConnectionManager.FileServerPort +
                                  "/binary/up/" + category + "/" +  
                                  Path.GetFileName(filename) + "/" + safehash);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < ____)
        {
            reqStream.Write(bytes, offset, _________);
             _______
             _______
             _______

        }
        reqStream.Close();

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _____________
        }
        return safehash;
```

**Using WebClient (corrupt file on server end):**

```
      var client = new WebClient();
      client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "binary/octet-stream");

      client.UploadFile(new Uri("http://" +
              ConnectionManager.FileServerAddress + ":" +
              ConnectionManager.FileServerPort +
              "/binary/up/" + category + "/" +
              Path.GetFileName(filename) + "/" + safehash), filename);

      return safehash;
```

Server side is a WCF service:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "up/file/{fileName}/{hash}")]

    void FileUpload(string fileName, string hash, Stream fileStream);
```

Comment: If your target is a WCF service, is there a reason you aren't consuming it *as* a service, and instead trying to manually post data to it? What kind of file sizes are we talking about uploading here? WCF has some pretty small default file size limits. Are you having a keep-alive or a timeout issue with the `WebClient` implementation? Are you getting any exceptions on your end?

Comment: If you look at the request in a tool such as Fiddler, does it show any differences between the two?

Comment: Fiddler.. hmmmm good idea. I will check now. Cory: no issues on either end, just a corrupt file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebClient.UploadFile` sends the data in a multipart/form-data format. What you want to use to have the equivalent to the code using HttpWebRequest is the `WebClient.UploadData` method:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/octet-stream";
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
client.UploadData(new Uri("http://" + ConnectionManager.FileServerAddress + ":" +
       ConnectionManager.FileServerPort +
       "/binary/up/" + category + "/" +
       Path.GetFileName(filename) + "/" + safehash), fileContents);
```

Comment: Bingo! I was not expecting such a simple resolution. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that WebClient.UploadData has a bug in that it does not report the upload progress correctly :(. Guess I'll stick to my custom HttpWebRequest