# WebClient UploadFile corrupts binary data

Tags: c#, php, xamarin.ios, webclient

I am trying to synchronize binary files (photos) from my `Monotouch` application, running on an `iPad`, to our `PHP` server (Windows) using `Webclient`. The files are being sent and received, but the binary files seem to be corrupt on the server and cannot be viewed.

Here is the client side code:

```
static void UploadPhotos()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    string sUri = GetUri();
    client.UploadFile (sUri, "POST", "images/test.png");
}
```

And here is the `PHP` code on the server:

```
<?php
$uploadDir = "C:\\uploaddir\\";
foreach ($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array) {
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . $file_array['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'], $uploadFile);
}
?>
```

Does anyone know why the binary data gets corrupted in the upload and how to fix it?

**Update:**

Very strange indeed. It seems the problem I am having affects `png` images only; `jpeg` images seem to come across correctly. The `jpeg` images show the image dimensions correctly in windows explorer on the server and I am able to preview the `jpeg` images. The `jpeg` images that I tested were about 90 KB. The `png` files though are not coming across correctly. In windows explorer the `png` files don't show the dimensions of the images and cannot be previewed. The `png` file sizes are larger on the server. So, for example, I use the following `png` image:

http://tuxpaint.org/stamps/stamps/animals/birds/cartoon/tux.png

The initial file is 40.2 KB (41236 bytes); after transfer the file size on the server is 45.3 KB (46468 bytes). Anyone got any ideas how this could happen?

Comment: Do the file sizes match?  Have you tried doing the upload using the same code from a simple windows client?  That would help determine if the problem is the client or the server.  You should also try to upload a small text file - is it possible there is a file size limit on the server that is causing a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Content-Type to "application/octet-stream", I think that's more common for binary data and the server may not recognize binary/octet-stream.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I did not even notice the "binary/octet-stream"; that came from a copy/paste from a website somewhere. I have replaced it with "application/octet-stream", but unfortunately it still does not work correctly.

Comment: It still seems to upload as something other than binary. This post alludes to it using multipart/form-data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642536/httpwebrequest-works-webclient-uploadfile-doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I had to use UploadDataAsync

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
           client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
           byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
           client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(url), bytes);
        }
```