# WebClient's UploadFile and UploadData not sending same headers (with multipart/form-data)

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to integrate a file upload with an API, which is very explicit about how they want the data being sent:

> You can make POST request formatted as multipart/form-data. The field of the file should be named file.

Bearing in mind **I haven't got access to the file** itself (I've got a `byte[]`) means I can't use the `WebClient.UploadFile(url, filePath)`.

Instead, I've got the `WebClient.UploadData(url, byte[])`which is supposed to fit pretty well into my needs.

Thing is, if I use the `UploadData` method instead of `UploadFile` the API feels like it's not being sent yet (*updated this question with more info*), which is not happening with the `UploadFile` method.

I specify the `client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "binary/octet-stream"` headers which is the one which works with the `UploadFile` method.

I've tried with `"multipart/form-data"` with no luck. I'm pretty sure I'm failing in something related to this "header thing". Any information or help will be greatly appreciated.

**Working** WebClient's `UploadFile` method:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "binary/octet-stream";
    string url = processUrl + $"?input=upload&format={file.Extension}&file={file.Name}";
    var result = client.UploadFile(url, fileData);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
}
```

**Not working** WebClient's `UploadData` method:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "binary/octet-stream";
    string url = processUrl + $"?input=upload&format={file.Extension}&file={file.Name}";
    var result = client.UploadData(url, data);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
}
```

I preferred focusing on making it work and afterwards I will simply migrate it to `async`.

P.S: I found other questions like this one ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12785411/3563910) or [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10643051/3563910)) but none of them worked.

**EDIT**: this is what actually Fiddler shows with both requests:

UploadFile's:

> POST
>   https://heidi.infra.cloudconvert.com/process/950a6550-e4ba-46f2-8d20-7ffe7c0309c3?input=upload&format=pdf&file=c%3a%2ftemp%2fprueba.docx&email=
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=---------------------8d68062f657b700 Host:
>   heidi.infra.cloudconvert.com Content-Length: 12842 Expect:
>   100-continue
>
> -----------------------8d68062f657b700 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="prueba.docx" Content-Type: binary/octet-stream

UploadData's:

> POST
>   https://roberta.infra.cloudconvert.com/process/950a6550-e4ba-46f2-8d20-7ffe7c0309c3?input=upload&format=pdf&file=prueba.docx
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: binary/octet-stream Host:
>   roberta.infra.cloudconvert.com Content-Length: 12652 Expect:
>   100-continue

What the API expects:

> POST https://srv01.cloudconvert.com/upload/~Gl47wdgf6 Content-Type:
>   multipart/form-data; boundary=foo_bar_baz Content-Length:
>   number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body
>
> --foo_bar_baz Content-Disposition: file; filename="inputfile.jpg" Content-Size: 98344 Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> ... JPEG data ...

Comment: _"the API feels like it's not being sent yet"_ - please don't talk about API's feelings, tell us exactly what you observe. Inspect the requests with a tool like Fiddler to compare the differences. What format does the API expect?

Comment: @CodeCaster my apologies. I've just updated the question with the Fiddler's log and what the API expects. I have just noticed the obvious difference between the headers added with each request I send but I'm afraid I haven't figured out how to fix it yet.