# Difference between UploadData and UploadFile WebClient

Tags: c#, rest, webclient

[Basically the same as this guy, unfortunately the thread died before being answered.][WebClient's UploadFile and UploadData not sending same headers (with multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306667/webclients-uploadfile-and-uploaddata-not-sending-same-headers-with-multipart-f)

I can upload a file using the WebClients UploadFile, but I'm unable to upload the same exact file converted to a byte array using UploadData.

Fiddler difference:
On UploadData: Content-Length: 13264

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8d77fde3018f8e5

On UploadFile: Content-Length: 13457

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8d77fdcfcc453c5

Why is this happening? Currently the file i have is stored in memory and not on file, and saving the file locally isn't really an option.

Anyone has any ideas?

EDIT:

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("dummy.pdf");


    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Access-Token", token);
        client.Headers.Add("Client-Secret", clientSecret);

        client.UploadFile("website", "dummy.pdf");

    }
    string boundary = "---------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    var newLine = Environment.NewLine;
    var fileHeaderFormat = "--"+boundary + newLine +
                           "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"" + newLine +
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + newLine + newLine;


    var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"website");
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    req.Headers.Add("Access-Token", token);
    req.Headers.Add("Client-Secret", clientSecret);
    req.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        Type.DefaultBinder, req.Headers, new object[] { "Connection", "Keep-Alive" }
    );


    using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var reqWriter = new StreamWriter(reqStream);
        var tmp = string.Format(fileHeaderFormat, "file", "dummy.pdf");
        reqWriter.Write(tmp);
        reqWriter.Flush();
        reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    var res = req.GetResponse();
    using (var resStream = res.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
        var t = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are converting the file to a byte array?

Comment: var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("dummy.pdf");
In the other scenario I'm getting a byte array in response of a request to a pdf generator.

Comment: `but I'm unable to upload the same exact file converted to a byte array using UploadData` are you seeing any errors, what's the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: No errors, except I'm getting a bad request back from the website.

Comment: The only thing thats different is the file size, where UploadFile seems to add some data to the file, while UploadFile does not.

Comment: Can you show your current code for both methods please?

Comment: Posted below, they look identical on fiddler.

Comment: Debug into the reference code and that might reveal more information https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs